# Angular material form based on type properties

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material

I have a dialog component which shows when I click an 'Edit' button next to an item in a table. The dialog component looks like this for now:

```
    <h1 mat-dialog-title>{{item.ID}}</h1>
<div mat-dialog-content>
    <p>Edit item</p>
    <mat-form-field appearance="outline" style="justify-content: center;">
        <mat-label>ID</mat-label>
        <input matInput [(ngModel)]="item.ID">
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
        <mat-label>Name</mat-label>
        <input matInput [(ngModel)]="item.Name">
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
        <mat-label>Date</mat-label>
        <input matInput [(ngModel)]="item.Date">
    </mat-form-field>
</div>
<div mat-dialog-actions style="justify-content: center;">
    <button mat-button (click)="onNoClick()">Cancel</button>
    <button mat-button [mat-dialog-close]="item.ID" cdkFocusInitial>Save</button>
</div>
```

This looks and works fine, and serves its purpose. But now I have several other tables with different types of data, and while I can create a separate dialog for each table and add the form fields manually for each type, I would like to have a more flexible solution.

How can I create a dialog where form fields are added based on the reference element's type?
E.g: If I have an object of type 'Fruit' in one table with properites like 'Name', 'Color', 'Price', and an object of type 'Car' with properties like 'Name', 'Manufactured', 'Horsepower', can I use the same dialog component and create the form dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

Of course it is possible to make a single universal dynamic form, but it will become too difficult. As soon as there will be a need for logic for only one type of object (for example to disabling field "a" if a certain value in field "b" is selected).